# Help Identifying a component via image (looks like a varistor)

Tags: identification, components

I am having trouble identifying the following component:
[image: unkown component]

It is in circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZmYl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the circuit I would have expected it to be a pulldown resistor style to indicate that the connector is plugged in. The other pins of the connector are a wind sensor pulse output.

Any help is greatly apreciated,
Thanks

---

Update : After the helpful insight about checking it to be a PTC of NTC thermister I performed measurements and it was 22kOhms. Held it with my fingers and it decreased to 20k and breathing on it I managed to get it to go down to 18k.

In circuit measurements with the Vcc = 5V, across the thermistor it was 1.4 V approx.

So **It is an NTC resistor**

And it makes sense that it be an NTC resistor because when the weather is too cold, the wind sensor could freeze up and you would not know if the measurement is valid. The resistance would go up and therefore the voltage and that would be tending to a similar scenario as if the sensor was disconnected. i.e. Open circuit.

Comment: Connect an ohm meter in both ends and then warm the part with your hand (you could place it in the freezer in advance for biggest effect) while observing the resistance. Then you'll see 1)  if it is a thermistor and 2) if so whether it is PTC or NTC.

Comment: NTC would make hardly any sense in the shown circuit, unless it is meant to detect freezing

Comment: @tobalt Why not? This exact schematic could be taken from your average Li/Ion battery charger. They all use NTC for some reason.

Comment: @Lundin, because the MCU signal will be already low at room temperature. If the device overheats, it will be just drawn more low.

Comment: @tobalt And that's exactly how battery chargers work, shutting off when they detect an unexpected rise in current, so...?

Comment: @Lundin but this circuit will not detect the change in current ? The MCU pin will read a low state either way. It would work if R1 was 10k. The way it is shown, it will only change state if the device is freezing.

Comment: @tobalt I'm assuming the MCU pin is an ADC input channel. If it is a CMOS GPIO pin then it wouldn't make any sense indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your discussion and comments to bring other ideas into the mix. It turned out to be an NTC thermistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a type of a thermistor (NTC or PTC).
Their resistance changes with temperature. 22K would be the resistance at room temperature (25°C).
Perhaps more info about the device would help with identifying the part, but I would suggest you trying to warm up / cool down the part and measure its resistance with your multimeter.

If it changes significantly, then it is probably a thermistor.
There are usually two types of thermistors: Negative and Positive temperature coefficient.
NTC thermistor's resistance lowers with higher temperature, PTC vise versa.
More about thermistors [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor).

Comment: aha, thankyou for the insight, I will try to perform some measurements this afternoon/evening. That would make sense acting as a double function. 1. to know if the connector is connected and 2. it would indicate that when freezing temperatures are present the wind sensor input should not be considered valid.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. They are usually not super precise (± a few degrees), but for detecting, if it is freezing, they are alright.

Comment: Did the measurements and it was indeed an NTC with what I'm guessing would be nominal resistance of 22k@25ºC